# Abrir View com Parâmetros

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, view

Tenho este Script:

```
$('#Musico').change(function () {
    var id = $(Musico).val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("Votar","Chamada")';
    var tipo = 1;

    $(function ChamaVotar() {
        $.post(url, { id: id, tipo: tipo });
    });//Function ChamaVotar

});//musico change
```

E este controller:

```
public ActionResult Votar(int id, int tipo)
{
    if (tipo == 1)//Tipo Musico
    {
        var chamadaMusicas = db.ChamadaMusicas.Include(c => c.Chamada).Include(c => c.Musica).Where(c => c.Chamada.PessoaID.Equals(id)).Where(i => i.Chamada.Ativa.Equals(true)).ToList();
        return View(chamadaMusicas);
    }
    else//Local
    {
        var chamadaMusicas = db.ChamadaMusicas.Include(c => c.Chamada).Include(c => c.Musica).Where(c => c.Chamada.LocalID.Equals(id)).Where(i => i.Chamada.Ativa.Equals(true)).ToList();
        return View(chamadaMusicas);
    }
}
```

Eu preciso que, ao passar meus parâmetros para o controller, a view seja aberta. Porém ela não está abrindo... O controller recebe a informação mas não abre a página. Qual solução pra isso?

Comment: Não sei se é a forma mais adequada de fazer isso, deveria colocar um form na view que pega os parametros e dar um submit, desse jeito vc só está dando o post, não tem nenhuma instrução no seu javascript para redirecionar para a view retornada pelo controller.

Answer (score 4):

Tente construir a url desta forma:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' + '?id=' + id + '&tipo=' + tipo;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
         // faz alguma coisa
    }
});
```

Obs.: estou editando a resposta porque estava errada.

Comment: Alexadre bom dia, ontem aos 45 do segundo tempo, consegui resolver de forma similar a isto, estava tão exausto que não respondi minha própria pergunta... mas a ideia é esta mesmo. Valeu

Answer (score 4):

A solução que encontrei para resolver meu problema foi da maneira a seguir, onde o `id` e `tipo` foram passados por parâmetros via URL. Para que a janela fosse aberta utilizei o `window.location.replace` (que abre na mesma janela, sem abrir uma nova guia).

```
$('#Musico').change(function () {
    var id = $(Evento).val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("Votar", "Chamada")';
    var tipo = 2;
    window.location.replace(url + '?id=' + id + '&tipo=' + tipo);

});
```

Comment: Blz, mas usando windows.location, voce vai recarregar a tela, certo? se voce utilizar a solução que postei, dentro do success voce pode atualizar sua pagina ou mandar um popup de confirmação para o usuário sem fazer o refresh da tela. É claro, isso depende da sua necessidade, fica só a sugestão.

Comment: Não sei se estou errado, é que na tela que passo os parâmetros é uma, a que recebe é outra, então acho que seria sim necessário abrir uma nova página. Ainda estou aprendendo e não sei bem como tratar estas coisas. Isto é um projeto para a Faculdade e o tempo está curto pra nós rsrsrs... o importante é funcionar kkkk Mas valeu mesmo Alexandre